# copy files during GCP instance creation from python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

I am using the `googleapiclient` in python to launch VM instances. As part of that I am using the facility to run start up scripts  to install docker and other python packages.

Now, one thing I would like to do is copy files to this instance ideally during the instance creation stage through python code.

What might be the way to achieve this? Ideally what would work is to be able to detect that the instance has booted and then be able to copy these files.

Comment: Where is the Python code running (on the VM or at a management program that creates the VM instance)? As a tip, you can store files on Cloud Storage and use the CLI `gcloud` to copy files from Cloud Storage to the instance. The CLI is executed as part of your startup script. However, I would not do any of that. I would launch a VM, install what I required and then create a GCE Image that I then use to launch new instances with all required programs and files already installed.

Comment: The python code is running on the management program that creates the VM instance. The issue is that the  stuff being transferred to the VM instance is sort of sensitive and I would not like to store it in some persistent image. They are essentially SSH keys which have very limited time validity anyway, so I have to generate them every time the VM is created and I can (for various reasons) only generate them from the management program.

Comment: 1) Edit your question with more details. As written your question is too broad for Stackoverflow. 2) In regards to SSH keys, they don't expire so provide more details on what you mean there. 3) Data is just as safe (or unsafe) in a GCE Image as Cloud Storage or your own computer.

Comment: 4) If your code is running outside of the instance, then you will either need to remote control the VM using SSH, use SCP/SSH to transfer files which can be done in Python, write your own agent that runs on the instance or write a script that uses the CLI to download files. Each method has its own limitations and reliability issues to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am hearing you correctly, you want files to be present inside the container that is being executed by Docker in your Compute Engine VM.  Your Startup Script for the Compute Engine is installing docker.

My recommendation is not to try and copy those files into the container but instead, have them available on the local file system available to the Compute Engine.  Configure your docker startup to then mount the directory from the Compute Engine into the docker container.  Inside the docker container, you would now have accessibility to the desired files.

As for bringing the files into the Compute Engine environment in the first place, we have a number of options.  The core story however will be describing where the files start from in the first place.

One common approach is to keep the files that you want copied into the VM in a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket/folder.  From there, your startup script can use GCS API or the gsutil command to copy the files from the GCS bucket to the local file system.

Another thought, and again, this depends on the nature of the files ... is that you can create a GCP disk that simply "contains" the files.  When you now create a new Compute Engine instance, that instance could be defined to mount the disk which is shared read-only across all the VM instances.

Comment: Thanks fo the answer. Yes, that is absolutely fine. However, I am not sure how to get it into the VM instance in the first place. I do not see any option on how I can pass the files during instance creation? i would like to do everything from within python, if possible.

Comment: Ive update the answer with some thoughts on getting the data into the VM.  Its likely we will want to understand where the data originates from and how static it may be.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest to use tool like Terraform or Google Deployment Manager to create cloud infrastructure instead of writing custom python code and handling all edge-cases by yourself.

For some reason, you can't use above tool and only Python program is an option for you the you can do following:
1. Create a GCS bucket using python api and put appropriate bucket policy to protect data.
2. Create a service account which has read permission to above GCS bucket.
3. Launch VM instance using python API and have your start-up script to install packages and run docker container. Attach above service account which has permission to read files from above GCS bucket.
3. Have a startup script in your docker container which can run ``gsutil` command to fetch files from GCS bucket and put at the right place.

Hope this helps.

Again, if you can use tools like Terraform, that will make things easy.